# Menus (eg, right-click windows) are not being drawn on the screen

Tags: unity, menu, xdg-open

The "context menus" which normally show up on right-click, as well as other pull-downs (for example `evince`'s resize screen or any program's at-the-top menu pulldowns) are invisible.

This is Ubuntu 12.04.

I know the computer still *thinks* it's drawing them because of the way left-click responds. But I can't see its contents.

What program draws these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [How can I restart the menu bar in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340816/how-can-i-restart-the-menu-bar-in-unity?rq=1)

Restarting `unity` solved the problem. This can be accomplished without `killall unity`; I just did `unity` and that worked.

Comment: Although this solution wasn't without problems. Restarting `unity` ruined my browser session by confusing `chromium` about what had been open.

Comment: **Warning** I typed `unity` and it just flashed the screen and removed all window borders, and shortcuts like `alt-tab` and `ctrl-Q` stopped working. My only option was to reboot in another tty and **lose unsaved data**. (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity) [Edit] I read the link and I think you meant to say `setsid unity`.

Comment: [edit2] That sill closes all programs. Multiple people in the other topic also reported that